# Deploying a custom assembly to SSRS in Sharepoint Integrated Mode

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I'm having some trouble deploying a custom assembly used in some of my reports to our SSRS server in Sharepoint integrated mode. [According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155034) the two methods to deploy an assembly to SSRS are:

1. Copying the assembly to %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRSnn.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
2. Installing it to the GAC

I've tried both of those and I still get this error when deploying reports:

```
Deploying report 'http://localhost:7000/shared documents/xxxxxx.rdl'.
Error rsProcessingError : Error while loading code module: ‘Xxxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Xxxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The assembly is definitely in ReportServer\bin. It's also in Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies and it does work in the Preview mode in Visual Studio. I also used gacutil to install it to the GAC, but it is still not found.

Is there some special place I need to put the assembly to make it work with SSRS in Sharepoint? I can't seem to find any information about this. Is there some other reason I would get that error?

Comment: I am having the same exact issue, and have tried everything I can think of up until this point.  I'd also love an answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

The custom assembly needs to be copied to:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting\bin

The rssrvpolicy.config file that will need updating is here:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting

Source:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d76c2d9-09f1-4045-adf4-a78d32c1b113/ssrs-report-with-custom-assembly-error?forum=sqlreportingservices

From Microsoft Docs:

By default, the installation directory for SharePoint mode is the following:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-configuration-files?view=sql-server-2014#bkmk_config_file_Summary_sharepoint_mode